# Finding text string with pfdminer not consistent [Python]

Tags: python, string, return-value, pdfminer

I've got a question about a code that's getting text string from a pdf file and returns the output in a .csv

The output is stored in [Output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQvk.png). Like you can see it returns value on p.27 [here the code works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a75Qe.jpg) and 29, p. 28 is missing. What i want to return is [textstring on p. 28 code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0R0w.jpg).

Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong? In the 2nd code pdfminer does read out the proper output that is needed.

```
import re, csv, os
import sys, time
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mp
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from pathlib import Path
from io import StringIO
try:
  from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
  from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
  from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
  from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
except ImportError:
  print ("Trying to Install required module: pdfminer\n")
  os.system('python -m pip install pdfminer')
# -- above lines try to install requests module if not present
# -- if all went well, import required module again ( for global access)


# method 3: object oriented programming
class Program:
    #initialisation (happens when Program() is called for the first time)
    def __init__(self):

        # locations
        # this defines the location of the workspace and directory of the data to process
        self.ws_loc = Path("C:/Users/pco/Desktop/workspace")
        self.dat_loc = Path("C:/Users/pco/Desktop/workspace/data/Test")
        
        # lookuptable
        # this converts the lookuptable from maximo to a list which can be used for comparison
        self.lu_file = self.ws_loc / "lookuptable.csv"
        with open(self.lu_file, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            self.lu_list = list(filter(None,list(reader)))
            self.lu_list = [each[0] for each in self.lu_list]


    def listener(self,q):
        '''listens for messages on the q (queue), writes (appends) to file (output.csv). '''
        # open output.csv in location workspace/data/ and use as 'f'
        with open(self.ws_loc / 'output.csv', 'a') as f:
            
            #start infinite listening loop until 'kill' message is received
            while 1:
                
                # get the message which is first in q (queue)
                m = q.get()
                
                # break loop if message is kill and close file 'output.csv'
                if m == 'kill':
                    f.close()
                    break
                
                # if message is not 'kill' then write message to file and flush file
                f.write(m)
                f.flush()

      
    def worker(self, file, q):
        ''' processes a pdf file given by main() and writes output to q (queue)'''
        
        # init PDF class (this class is used to get pages from the PDF and process pdftext)
        PDF = self.PDF(self.dat_loc,self.lu_list,0)
        
        # get all the pages from PDF: contains pages = [page1, ..., pageN]
        # pageN = "bla bla \n bla etc."
        PDFpages = PDF.getPages(file)
        pages = []
        for page in PDFpages:
            pages.append(page)
        
        # varargs defines extra data for files (this is where metadata is stored)
        # varargs should not be filled here, but it is initialized here.
        varargs = ''
        
        # check if file is a manual (this can be seen as an example for a varargs entry)
        # it should contain atleast ',' (this creates a new column entry in the csv)
        # PDF.fileCategory() which is a class within the Program class, can be taken as an example
        varargs+= PDF.fileCategory(file,pages) + ',' + PDF.fileSupplier(file, pages) + ',' + PDF.fileRev(file, pages)
        # new vararg can be added like: varargs+= THE_VARARG
        
        # initialise pageNum (which is a page number identifier inside the for loop)
        pageNum = 1
        
        # create an empty datastack (which is the message that will be send to q (queue))
        datastack = ''
        
        # for each page do...
        for page in pages:
            
            '''!!! for each page look for tags (THIS IS WHERE THE REGEX HAPPENS PDF.find_tag()) !!!'''
            found_strings, found = PDF.find_tag(page)
            # found_stringsrev, foundrev = PDF.find_rev(page)
            
            # if tags are found, then fix the tags such that they are correct with
            # Program.putStripe() (or self.putStripe()) it changes 12AB1234A to 12-AB-1234-A
            # if foundrev:
            #     string = ''
            #     fixedstring = ''
            #     for stringrev in found_stringsrev:
            #         # fill datastack with found tags
            #         datastack += file + ',' + str(pageNum) + ',' + string + ',' + fixedstring + ',' + stringrev + ',' + varargs + '\n'
                    
            if found:
                for string in found_strings:
                    # if correct, do not change
                    fixedstring = string
                    
                    # check if the tag matches the correct regexpression ('regex' or 're')
                    if re.match('^(\d{1,2}[ -]{,1}[A-Z]{1,4}[ -]{,1}\d{4}[ -]{,1}[A-Z]*).*$', string)!=None:
                        
                        # else fix the tag
                        fixedstring = self.putStripe(string)
                        
                    # fill datastack with found tags
                    datastack += file + ',' + str(pageNum) + ',' + string + ',' + fixedstring + varargs + '\n'
            
            
            # next page, so pageNum becomes pageNum + 1
            pageNum +=1
        
        # if the datastack is empty, we are still interested in the varargs:
        # (so empty tag columns are added)
        if datastack=='':
            datastack = file + ',' + ',' + ',' + varargs + '\n'
        
        # put the datastack message inside of the q (queue)
        q.put(datastack)
        
        # terminate the PDF class so that the pdf file is closed in a correct way
        PDF.terminate()
        
        # return (in case the datastack should be printed)
        return datastack
    
    
    def putStripe(self,input):
        '''This function fixes a tag that is not correct'''
        # strip the tag from spaces
        input = re.sub(' ','',input)
        
        # for each string that matches the expression write to words
        words = re.findall('[0-9][A-Za-z]+', input)
        words += re.findall('[A-Za-z][0-9]+', input)
        
        # for each match inside the tag add a '-' in the second position
        for word in words:
            i = input.find(word)+1
            input = input[:i] + '-' + input[i:]
        
        # return the fixed tag
        return input
    
    def main(self):
        try:
            # initiate time
            t = time.time()
            
            # create pools for paralell pooling (max cpu threads is optained automatically)
            pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() + 2)
            
            # create a manager
            manager = mp.Manager()
            
            # from the pool manager create a queue object which can be used to 
            # exchange data between the worker and listener
            q = manager.Queue()
            
            # start up listener first
            # ignore warning, it is being used
            watcher = pool.apply_async(self.listener, (q,))
            
            # fire off workers (basically assign them jobs)
            jobs = []
            
            # NOTE: FOR LOOPS DO NOT CAUSE A LOOP, CODE PROCEEDS WITH PARALLEL THREADING
            # AS IF THE RESULT OF EACH LOOP IS INSTANTLY COMPLETED
            # each file in the data location is a job
            for file in os.listdir(self.dat_loc):
                # assign the job to a worker
                job = pool.apply_async(self.worker, (file, q))
                # append the job to jobs (for data aquisition)
                jobs.append(job)
            
            # this is used to get the data back from jobs
            for job in tqdm(jobs):
                #print('')
                #print(job.get()[:-1])
                job.get()
            
            # printed elapsed time (good for project management)
            print('elapsed time = ' + str(time.time()-t) + ' seconds')
        
        # catch interupt and try to properly terminate workers (might take time)
        # best to just do everything in batches and dont interrupt
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nCaught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers")
            q.put('kill') # <-- makes sure the output.csv is always closed properly
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            pool.terminate()
            SystemExit(1)
        
        # always excecute (kills workers and listener)
        finally:
            q.put('kill') # <-- makes sure the output.csv is always closed properly
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

    def execute(self):
        self.main()

    class PDF:
        # from PDF.
        def __init__(self,dat_loc,lu_list,maxpages):
            self.dat_loc = dat_loc
            self.lu_list = lu_list
            self.lu_list_f = 0
            self.password = ""
            self.maxpages = maxpages
            self.caching = True
            self.rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
            self.retstr = StringIO()
            self.laparams = LAParams()
            self.device = TextConverter(self.rsrcmgr, self.retstr, laparams=self.laparams)
            self.interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(self.rsrcmgr, self.device)
            self.pagenos=set()
        
        # from PDF.
        def getPages(self,file):
            self.fp = open(self.dat_loc / file, 'rb')
            pages = PDFPage.get_pages(self.fp,
                                      self.pagenos,
                                      maxpages=self.maxpages,
                                      password=self.password,
                                      caching=self.caching,
                                      check_extractable=True)
            return pages
        
        # from PDF.
        def fileCategory(self,file,pages):
            rules = []
            rules.append(['Manual',['ANLAGE - INSTALLATION','User Guide','MANUAL','Manual','manual','Handleiding','handleiding','Instruction','instructions','Instructie', 'Guide', 'GUIDE']])
            rules.append(['Specification',['SPECIFICATION','Specification','Specificatie']])
            rules.append(['Datasheet',['DATA BOOK','UTILITIES LIST','DATA PACKAGE','Data Package','data-sheet','Datasheet','DATASHEET','datasheet','DATA SHEET','Data Sheet','Data sheet','data sheet']])
            rules.append(['Spare part list',['SPARE PARTS LIST']])
            rules.append(['Invoice',['BILL OF MATERIAL','invoice','Invoice','INVOICE','Purchase order','Purchase Order','PURCHASE ORDER']])
            rules.append(['Schematic Diagram',['SCHEMATIC DIAGRAM','Schematic Diagram','Schematic diagram', 'ISOMETRIC', 'Isometric', 'isometric']])
            rules.append(['Checklist', ['Checklist', 'CHECKLIST', 'CHECKSHEET', 'Checksheet']])
            rules.append(['Certificates', ['Certificate', 'CERTIFICATE', 'Zertifikat', 'ZERTIFIKAT', 'Certificat', 'CERTIFICAT']])
            rules.append(['Required documents list', ['REQUIRED SUBMITTAL DOCUMENTS']])
            
            fileCategory = ''

            found = False
            counter = 1
            for page in pages:
                if counter>4:
                    break
                for rule in rules:
                    category = rule[0]
                    category_rules = rule[1]
                    for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():
                        if any(line.find(x)!=-1 for x in category_rules):
                            found = True
                        if found:
                            break
                    if found:
                        break
                if found:
                    break
                counter+=1
            if found:
                fileCategory += ',' + category
            else:
                fileCategory += ',' + 'Unreadable'
            return fileCategory
        
     # from PDF.
        def fileSupplier(self,file,pages):
            rules = []
            rules.append(['JE Jacobs',['JE Jacobs', 'JE JACOBS', 'Jacobs', 'JACOBS']])
            rules.append(['Emerson',['Emerson', 'Emerson Process Management', 'EMERSON',]])
            rules.append(['Air Liquide',['Air Liquide', 'AIR LIQUIDE']])
            rules.append(['Rosemount',['ROSEMOUNT', 'Rosemount']])
            rules.append(['Deltak',['Deltak', 'DELTAK']])
            rules.append(['AviComp',['AVICOMP', 'Avicomp', 'avicomp']])
            
            fileSupplier = ''

            found = False
            counter = 1
            for page in pages:
                if counter>4:
                    break
                for rule in rules:
                    category = rule[0]
                    category_rules = rule[1]
                    for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():
                        if any(line.find(x)!=-1 for x in category_rules):
                            found = True
                        if found:
                            break
                    if found:
                        break
                if found:
                    break
                counter+=1
            if found:
                fileSupplier += ',' + category
            else:
                fileSupplier += ',' + 'Supplier N/A'
            return fileSupplier
        
        # from PDF.
        def fileRev(self,file,pages):            
            fileRev = ''

            found = False
            counter = 1
            for page in pages:
                if counter>4:
                    break
                for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():
                        if re.match('^(Rev.*).*$', line):
                            found = True
                        if found:
                            break
                if found:
                    break
                counter+=1
            if found:
                fileRev += ',' + line
            else:
                fileRev += ',' + ''
            return fileRev
        
        # from PDF.
        def find_string_lookup(self,page,pageNum,file,varargs):
            datastack = []
            data = []
            found = False
            for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():
                line = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', line)
                counter = 0
                for tag in self.lu_list_f:
                    if line.find(tag)!=-1:
                        found = True
                        data = file + ',' + str(self.lu_list[counter][0]) + ',' + str(pageNum) + varargs +'\n'
                        if data not in datastack:
                            datastack += [data]
                    counter+=1
            return datastack, found
        
        # from PDF.
        def find_string(self,page,strings,Method=None):
            
            datastack = []
            data = []
            found = False
            if Method=='ALPHABET_NUM_ONLY':
                tags = [re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', line) for line in strings]
            elif Method=='ALPHABETCAPS_NUM_ONLY':
                tags = [re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', line).upper() for line in strings]
            elif Method=='ALPHABETCAPS':
                tags = [line.upper() for line in strings]
            else:
                tags = strings
            
            for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():
                if Method=='ALPHABET_NUM_ONLY':
                    line = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', line)
                elif Method=='ALPHABETCAPS_NUM_ONLY':
                    line = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', line).upper()
                elif Method=='ALPHABETCAPS':
                    line = line.upper()
                
                i = 0
                for tag in tags:
                    if tag != '':
                        if line.find(tag)!=-1:
                            found = True
                            data = strings[i]
                            if data not in datastack:
                                datastack += [data]
                    i+=1
            return datastack, found
        
        # from PDF.
        def find_tag(self,page):
            datastack = []
            found = False
            for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():                
                tags = re.findall('^(\d{2}[ -]{,1}[A-Z]{1,4}[ -]{,1}\d{4}[ -]{,1}[A-Z]*).*$', line)
                for tag in tags:
                    if tag not in datastack:
                        datastack += [tag]
                        found = True
            return datastack, found
        
         # from PDF.
        # def find_rev(self,page):
        #     datastack = []
        #     found = False
        #     for line in self.pagestr(page).splitlines():                
        #         tags = re.findall('^(Rev.*).*$', line)
        #         for tag in tags:
        #             if tag not in datastack:
        #                 datastack += [tag]
        #                 found = True
        #     return datastack, found
        
        
        # from PDF.
        def pagestr(self,page):
            self.retstr.truncate(0)
            self.retstr.seek(0)
            self.interpreter.process_page(page)
            return self.retstr.getvalue()
        
        # from PDF.
        def terminate(self):
            self.fp.close()
            self.device.close()
            self.retstr.close()

# start the code (the proper way)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Program().execute()
```

If i read out the pdf with this code in python (also with pdfminer):

```
from pathlib import Path
from io import StringIO
try:
  from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
  from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
  from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
  from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
except ImportError:
  print ("Trying to Install required module: pdfminer\n")
  os.system('python -m pip install pdfminer')
# -- above lines try to install requests module if not present
# -- if all went well, import required module again ( for global access)

class glb():
    workspace_folder = Path('C:/Users/pco/Desktop/workspace')
    data_folder = Path('C:/Users/pco/Desktop/workspace/data/Test')
    lookup_file = workspace_folder / "lookuptable.csv"
    with open(lookup_file, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        lookup_list = list(reader)
        lookup_list_filtered = list(filter(None,[re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(line)) for line in lookup_list]))
        
def find_tagnumbers(path):
    pagelines = []
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    page_no = 1
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        page_str = retstr.getvalue()
        pagelines.append(page_str.splitlines())
        retstr.truncate(0)
        retstr.seek(0)
        page_no +=1
    page_no +=-1
    print(pagelines)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return 1


find_tagnumbers('C:/Users/pco/Desktop/workspace/data/Test/1845613_1_27_Marked.pdf')
```

it does returns 47-AT -0053. But if i run the code below it doesn't return the value in output file. [Output when i print pagelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZTIh.jpg)

p.s. my coding skills is beginner (so i write out all the steps)

Comment: Is the question clear? Or do i need to clarify?

Comment: I've tried changing the parameters of LAParams, but without any succes